# Meaning of “May you drink cups of tea watching clouds of ambient sheep float across pastoral landscapes awash with pale sunlight.”

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> May you live in boring times. Like, the dullest times ever. May you drink cups of tea watching clouds of ambient sheep float across pastoral landscapes awash with pale sunlight. The pears in the orchard are slowly ripening. You haven't watched the news in seven years.

I can't understand this part of the tweet:

“May you drink cups of tea watching clouds of ambient sheep float across pastoral landscapes awash with pale sunlight.”

Can someone please explain this part to me in simple terms?

Answer (score 1):

The writer is just trying to say that he hopes the person he is addressing as a pleasant life. He's trying to say it in a whimsical and poetic way. So instead of just saying, "I hope you have a pleasant life", he says "I hope you spend your life sitting back drinking tea and watching the clouds", etc.

Specifically:

drink cups of tea: Tea is often considered a relaxing drink, or something you drink while relaxing. No one says, "Just sit back, relax, and drink a can of Red Bull." But "Sit back, relax, and drink a cup of tea."

watching clouds of ambient sheep: I'm not sure if he means literal clouds, and that these clouds look like sheep, or if he means literal sheep, and there are many of them. ("Clouds of something" is an idiom for "a lot of something".)

float across pastoral landscapes: "Pastoral" means "relating to peaceful country life". So again, you're watching either clouds float over a peaceful countryside or you're watching literal sheep wander around a peaceful countryside.

awash with pale sunlight: Not harsh, glaring light, but pale sunlight. Again, peaceful.

Answer (score 0):

"“May you drink cups of tea watching clouds of ambient sheep float across pastoral landscapes awash with pale sunlight.” - these are all restful, peaceful, relaxing things.

ambient
in British English
ADJECTIVE
**2.  creating a relaxing atmosphere**